# Nothing shows when I tried to fill Combobox with .csv filenames

Tags: c#, combobox, getopenfilename

I failed to fill combobox with csv filenames. I created the combobox by dragging from toolbox in Microsoft Visual Studio. I set the name of combobox to ChooseSampleSheet.

The following is my code:

```
private void ChooseSampleSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\UniFlow\Desktop\Europa-master\user interface\Europa design Y\Experiemnt_Gui");//Assuming Test is your Folder
  FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.csv"); //Getting Text files
  ChooseSampleSheet.DataSource = Files;
  ChooseSampleSheet.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

Also, I tried the following code:

```
private string path = (@"C:\Users\UniFlow\Desktop\Europa-master\user interface\Europa design Y\Experiemnt_Gui");

private void ChooseSampleSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<String> Configurations = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*.exe")
                                         .Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p))
                                         .ToList();
  ChooseSampleSheet.DataSource = Configurations;
}
```

But Neither of them works. Nothing shows in my combobox. I expected to see csv file names. So that I can click to open selected file afterwards (not show in in my code).

People suggested me to change the event. The following is my update.

```
private void form4_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\UniFlow\Desktop\Europa-master\user interface\Europa design Y\Experiemnt_Gui");//Assuming Test is your Folder
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.csv"); //Getting Text files

        ChooseSampleSheet.DataSource = Files;
        ChooseSampleSheet.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }



    private void ChooseSampleSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

However, nothing show in the combobox still.

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Breakpoints to determine if the **d** and **Configurations** holds the values you need to populate the combobox?

Comment: Why would you run that code in the SelectedIndexChanged event?  That event only runs when something is selected in the list, which probably is still empty.

Comment: Did you "subscribe" to the load event, or just copied the load event?  Use the OnLoad override instead, put your code in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong in your code however I think your code is at the wrong place. 
SelectedIndexChanged will get execute when you select something from the drop down. Since your drop down has not been filled with values , you can't fire that event.

Put the same code in form_load and you will see the values there.

```
     DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\UniFlow\Desktop\Europa-master\user interface\Europa design Y\Experiemnt_Gui");//Assuming Test is your Folder
    FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.csv"); //Getting Text files

    ChooseSampleSheet.DataSource = Files;
    ChooseSampleSheet.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: Hi, I move the code to form4_load, but nothing show in combobox still. I am going to edit my post. So that I can show my code.

Comment: Do you have CSV file in that folder? I tried in my local machine and it worked fine.

Comment: Also open the form in design mode, double click on the form. It will write form_load event for you. Put your code there and let me know.

Comment: Yes! "open the form in design mode, double click on the form. It will write form_load event for you." solved my problem! Thank you so much!!